# docker-compose only working in some directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I have a very weird problem: docker-compose isn't working in system-directories.
If i try to execute it in eg. /opt, /srv or /tmp he can't find my docker-compose.yml although the file exists, but if i try the same in /root it works perfectly fine.
[Image of commands and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZzEr.png)

Here are some version information:

```
root@myhost:~$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
root@myhost:~$ which docker-compose
/snap/bin/docker-compose
root@myhost:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
```

My history:

```
cd /opt/
ls docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up
cp docker-compose.yml ~/docker-compose.yml
cd ~
ls docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up
cat docker-compose.yml
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  hello_world:
    image: ubuntu
    command: [/bin/echo, 'Hello world']
```

I couldn't find anything on the internet so far and absolutely have no clue why this happens.
Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Try with `docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: `root@myhost:/opt# docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/docker-compose.yml'` In /opt i still get the error. In /root/ it's working

Answer (score 1):

I think you use snap package *docker-compose*
if You remove docker-compose from snap and install it using another method. For example:

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
#if need
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /snap/bin/docker-compose
sudo rm /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

After it you can launch your *docker-compose.yml* wherever you want.